# Worker threads with ts-node

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node, worker-thread

I am planning to have worker threads for socket.io rooms. I create a worker thread on the first connection to a room which then sets up firebase listeners.

Unfortunately. I have common imports in the worker file and my main source code.

I followed this article to allow running ts files via worker_threads -> https://wanago.io/2019/05/06/node-js-typescript-12-worker-threads/

Unfortunately, I dont get top-level await and upon starting the worker thread, I get the following error.
`error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'tslib_1'.\r\n"`

Here is my tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
  },
  "files": [
    "typings.d.ts"
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't provided any info on how you run your application, so I will suppose the following setup:

- you run your main application by requiring `ts-node` on command line:

  ```sh
  node -r ts-node/register index.ts
  ```
- your worker entry point is a `.ts` file, you instantiate it as follows:

  ```js
  new Worker('./worker.ts')
  ```
- you have the following code near the top of your worker script:

  ```js
  require('ts-node').register();
  ```

Assuming this is your setup, you need to remove the line

```js
require('ts-node').register();
```

from your worker entry point script. This line is basically causing your TypeScript file to be compiled twice by `ts-node`, hence the double declaration error for `tslib_1`.

Registering `ts-node` manually like above is only necessary, when your main program wan't started with the `-r ts-node/register` flag. If it was, then `ts-node` will be automatically required when you instantiate your worker and will compile the requested TS sources on-the-fly.

There are a few other gotchas that you have to keep in mind when using workers:

- The `new Worker(...)` API resolves the requested file relatively to your working directory, if you want to resolve relatively to the current souce file you'll need to do something like this: `new Worker(path.resolve(__dirname, './worker.ts'))`.
- If you don't use `ts-node` in production and instead compile your sources via `tsc`, you won't be able to load the worker script after your sources are compiled to JS, your worker file will become `worker.js` (mind the file extension). You'll need to detect this situation and change the path accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, your `The new Worker(...) API resolves the requested file relatively to your working directory` hint is what _I_ was missing!